# VS Coded UI - Actual Unit Tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, coded-ui-tests

I'm a C# and UI developer and I'm interested in writing **unit tests** in VS CodedUI for ASP.NET web applications. Most of the usages I've seen are **integration tests**, in that you write a test that points at the actual web page, run through some steps and test the output. I want something smaller and more granular, that is super simple for developers (read: lazy :P) to write.

My current setup looks like:

- Web application, containing pages, controls, javascript, etc.
- The web app also contains test pages - pages that contain a single user control in the markup, and some hard-coded data in the code-behind.
- A CodedUI project that launches the test page, runs the test and asserts the output.

This is a nice start, but I'm looking to improve it.

The (first...) problem is that the test data and the test steps are in different locations - on the web app and codedUI project respectively. In regular developer unit tests, you write code that sets the data, then you do everything else, and everything you need is in one location. With my setup, a person looking at a test failure has to know to look at both the test and the page being tested.

A few ideas I had, and why they suck:

1. Put the test page in the codedUI project. This is a problem for a few reasons. User controls can't be easily tested, was my stopping point, but I believe there are plenty of others.
2. Pass in a query-string to the test page that provides the data. This isn't a *terrible* idea, but it might get unwieldy quickly.
3. Pass in a public class to be loaded by the test page which contains the test data. This requires the test page to have a reference to the testing project, which is no good.
4. Dynamically write and compile a test page in the codedUI test. I don't even want to start with this.

Comment: So far I went with option #2, as it provides the best way of providing the test data closest to the tests themselves. The problem though is that the query string has a limited length, and while my current tests don't run up against it, future ones definitely will.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are talking about unit testing your web pages with external data. With CUIT, you can do that with [data driven CUIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624082.aspx).

Comment: I don't like it. It's to "automation"-testy and not "unit"-testy enough. I want the test data to be directly visible from where the test is being written.